# Opencart images not showing after manual import

Tags: php, opencart, online-store

I have the following problem - I am migrating website database from other platform to Opencart.

When I imported the images in oc_product using PHP, they are not showing in the website. The real issue is that if I manually change or type the image path, it works. Maybe it's some cache problem, but I cannot figure out why.

The images are not showing even in the admin panel - attaching picture [image: Opencart admin]

Here is also how my database look like - the image path is correct [image]

My Opencart version is 1.5.6.4

Any ideas?

Comment: special chars in the content that are not present when you manually type the values

Comment: sorry, didn't understand your point?

Answer (score 0):

obviously, the image path differs for the images, when we import and thus the imagepath has to be taken care before we actually import the data.And after importing then we have to run a sql query to change the imagepath in the database.

Comment: This is the correct image path. If I change the data/gallery/10.jpg manually to data/gallery/11.jpg it will work. Very weird...

Answer (score 0):

In the question you mention an import step performed using php.

I'm doing a wild guess but maybe that for whatever reason some unprintable character has been added and is messing up the whole thing.

The easiest way to check if this is the case is to analyze the html produced to verify if there is anything odd in the img tag path.

Another quick check is to export a few rows of data that are currently acting weird and analyze the content with a smart (that show special chars) text editor.

Comment: I assume that it might be also some encoding problem. But how can I check that...?

Comment: Browse the site and check the html. If there is any html entity in the src attribute of the img tag then that's likely the culprit.

Comment: It's not that simple in Opencart ;). It doesn't even try to show the image in the html.